# Why i am getting invalid project description while importing project?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to import an existing project in eclipse. However i am getting this error in the snapshot below.
This problem only exists when i try to import from my workspace. However if the same project is somewhere else, then i am able to import it successfully.
[image]

Answer (score 12):

I also faced the same problem. The trick bellow solved my problem:

- check the box **Copy project into workspace** while importing the existing project.

Answer (score 4):

you have **two** **solutions** and they works:

**1-** move your project package from workspace and place it in another root, then import to eclips.

or

**2-** rename your project package and then add it and it will fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

you have a project named `X` in your workspace still you are trying to import another project named `X` . you can fix it by deleting the existing project in eclipse and retry importing.

Fixes

- You can change your workspace and import this project in to the new workspace
- delete the project from eclipse and import without using copy project in to workspace

Android -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace, You must use General->Existing projects into workspace. It's probably a solution

Comment: I have a project named X in my workspace folder. I am trying to import this X project in eclipse. So you tell me that i cant import project from my workspace folder into eclipse ?

Comment: Yes you can't , make sure that you have unchecked copy project to workspace

Comment: Theres no need to change the name of project

Answer (score 2):

You should change workspace path.
For to do Change The Workspace Path:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have checked all the solution and finded that in most of cases "Changing the Project location" form Workspace worked in 80% cases. But for next 20%,i would recommend to do following:

1. Change the folder of Project and then Import it. (first do this)
2. If above does not worked, Rename the Project and then try importing it.

If still you are not getting success,check whether you are importing the project from 1 workspace folder to other or not.IF yes,then while importing the projects,check the option "Copy project into Workspace".

And even if you are not getting success, clik import --> General -->  Existing Project into Workspace.

PS --> If this solution worked for you,please vote-up as i am newbie here and hence need that to participate in major questions and answers.
[image: General Option Approach for Importing]